# Monotonicity and strict order relations

Tags: derivatives, monotone-functions

Suppose we have a function $g$ that is differentiable (and hence continuous) and **monotonically increasing** on the interval $[P,Q]$.

I know that this alone is not enough to imply that if $a,b\in [P,Q]$ and $a>b$, then $g(a)>g(b)$, because this is a strict order relation and we only know that $g$ is monotonically increasing.

However, it is definitely true that $\forall m,n\in\mathbb{R}$, if $m>n$ then $m^3>n^3$. This strict order relation is definitely true, even though the cubic function $x^3$ is only **monotonocally increasing** on $(-\infty,\infty)$. My thought is that this is true because the cubic function $x^3$ is strictly increasing except at $x=0$.

This gave me the following thought:

> **Question**
>
> Suppose there is a function $f(x)$ that is differentiable for all $x\in [P,Q]$. Also, $f(x)$ is strictly increasing  for $x\in[P,Q]$, except for **finitely many** values of $x$. And, over the interval $[P,Q], f$ is monotonically increasing.
>
> Is the following statement true?: $\forall m,n\in [P,Q]$, if $m>n$ then $f(m)>f(n)$

To clarify, the function is monotonocally increasing on $[P,Q]$, and it is only stationary at **finitely many** points. I made this restriction so that the graph of $f(x)$ has no "horizontal lines" in $[P,Q]$, and this should mean that the strict order relation holds.

To me, this is intuitively true, although I haven't been able to come up with a formal proof. Like the function $x^3$, the strict order relations will hold for my function $f$, because the function is only stationary at a finite number of points.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The function $f(x)=x^3$ is strictly increasing... What is the problem with $x=0$? If a function satisfies $f'(x)\ge 0$ and $f'(x)=0$ at isolated points, is is still strictly increasing.

Comment: Oh, I always thought that the definition of a strictly increasing function was $\forall x, f'(x)>0$. But now I realise, a better definition (and the correct one) would be a function $f$ such that $\forall m>n, f(m)>f(n)$. This would then make the function that I have defined a strictly increasing function. Thanks.

Comment: Precisely... an increasing function does not need to be differentiable, so the base definition should not use derivatives. what you have been using as a definition is more of a proposition: If $f$ is differentiable and $f'>0$ then $f$ is strictly increasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just prove it by contardiction. If $m>n$ and $f(n)=f(m)$ then $f(m)\geq f(x) \geq f(n)$ for all $x$ between $n$ and $m$ (by monotonicity)  which makes $f$ constant througout the interval $(n,m)$. But this contradicts your hypothesis.